# Set path to GeoIpDB in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, geoip

I'm having trouble setting path to GeoIp database in my asp.net application.

I have db file in my application root folder, but when i call

```
  using (var reader = new DatabaseReader("GeoLite2-City.mmdb"))
```

exception "file not found" is thrown.

When i pass full local path `@"d:\documents\vsprojects\app\GeoLite2-City.mmdb"` to DatabaseReader, application is working. Is there a way to fix this, because this would not work when i upload app to host?

Edit: When i try to access file directly, with `http://localhost:45500/GeoLite2-City.mmdb` i get an 404.3 error.